# Question about convergence and divergence of positive series,which means there exists no slowest convergent series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

- If positive series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is divergent,try to prove exist divergence
  positive series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$,which satisfies 
  $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n}=0$
- If positive series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent,try to prove exist convergence
  positive series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$,which satisfies $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$
- Also I wonder,about positive series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$,consider its sum sequence $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$.
  If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is divergent,how about the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n$
  It's also divergent?Or not？
  If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent,how about the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n$
  It's also convergent?Or not？

Comment: For the second part, I wonder if $b_n=\sqrt{a_n}$ would be an interesting starting point, since $a_n\to 0$ is required.

Comment: For the third part, the first question is a definite "also divergent".

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: What did you try? The first and second questions can be solved in similar ways, and the third question is clear if you plug in almost any sequence $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ and suppose $a_n>0$, we have the following results.

**Question 1**:

- If $a_n\!\not\to\!0$ there exist $\varepsilon>0$ and an increasing sequence $(n_1,n_2,...)$ such that $a_{n_i}\geq\varepsilon$ for all $i$.
  $$\text{Let $b_n=\varepsilon/i$ if $n\in(n_i)$ and $b_n=\min(a_n^2,1/n^2)$ otherwise,}$$
  then $\sum_nb_n\geq\varepsilon\sum_n1/n\to\infty$ and $b_n/a_n\leq1/n\to0$.
- If $a_n\to0$, let $b_n=\ln(S_{n+1}/S_n)$, then $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i=\ln(S_{n+1}/S_1)\to\infty$ and
  $$\frac{b_n}{a_n}=\frac1{a_n}\ln\left(\frac{S_n+a_{n+1}}{S_n}\right)=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\ln\left(1+\frac{a_{n+1}}{S_n}\right)^{\frac1{a_{n+1}}}.$$
  As $n\to\infty$, we have $a_{n+1}/S_n\to0$, so by the limit definition of $e$ it follows $(1+a_{n+1}/S_n)^{1/a_{n+1}}\to e^0=1$, thus $b_n/a_n\to0$ since $a_{n+1}/a_n\to1$.

**Question 2**:

- Suppose $S_n\to S$ then let $b_n=\sqrt{S-S_n}-\sqrt{S-S_{n+1}}$, it follows $\sum_nb_n\to\sqrt{S-S_1}$ and
  $$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{S-S_n}-\sqrt{S-S_{n+1}}}=\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\big(\sqrt{S-S_n}+\sqrt{S-S_{n+1}}\big)\to0.$$

**Question 3**:

- $a_n>0\ \Rightarrow\ S_n\!\not\to0\ \Rightarrow\ \sum_nS_n$ diverges.